# Excuting a shell script in code fails while it works in the terminal

Tags: .net, macos, docker, mono

I have a short program running on mono that builds a shell script to collect logs from a set of running docker containers. The script consist of a series of commands like the one below

```
docker logs $(docker ps -f ancestor=comp/bff -q) > bff.log
```

if I execute in the terminal it works as I expect. Running with the (F#) code below it fails with `docker: command not found` for each of the lines in the script

```
        let p = new System.Diagnostics.Process()
        p.StartInfo.FileName <- "sh"

        p.StartInfo.Arguments <- scriptPath
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute <- true
        p.Start() |> ignore
        p.WaitForExit()
```

So what's the trick to make execution of a script in code match the execution in the terminal

Comment: The Docker command is not available in a "vanilla" shell on most machines. Try running the "Docker quickstart terminal" as the first thing in the shell. On my machine, the script it actually starts is `/Applications/Docker/Docker Quickstart Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh`.

Comment: @Henrik I have docker beta for mac which works in my normal non-docker-toolbox terminal

Comment: Provide the full path to `docker` in the script.  `which docker` in the terminal will give you that

Comment: Or setup `startInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PATH"] = "/blah";` so `sh` can search for binaries.

Comment: @RuneFS The script runs in the terminal and can execute `docker` but you can't run `docker` in the terminal??  Is the `PATH` different in the script compared to the terminal?